# Why does GCC not allow inheriting from a private nested class when you are a friend?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, nested, friend

Same question is asked: Why does GCC allow inheriting from a private nested class?
For non template classes, its allowed to inherit from private nested classes,
if it is a friend, but not for template classes.
Is it a bug?

```
template<class Base>
class InheritFromBaseMember : public Base::MemberPrivate // error
{
    using PrivateMember = typename Base::MemberPrivate; // works fine
};

class MyBase{
    friend class InheritFromBaseMember<MyBase>;

    // another try to declare it friend
    template<class T>
    friend class InheritFromBaseMember;

    friend class AnotherClass;

    class MemberPrivate{};
};

class AnotherClass : public MyBase::MemberPrivate{}; // works fine

int main() {
    InheritFromBaseMember<MyBase>{};
}
```

Errormessage from g++ 5.3.0:

```
error: 'class MyBase::MemberPrivate' is private
     class MemberPrivate{};
           ^
error: within this context
 class InheritFromBaseMember : public Base::MemberPrivate // error
       ^
```

Comment: Are you sure about the compiler version? It compiles [here](https://godbolt.org/g/1uUkge) just fine with g++ 4.9.0 and greater, including 5.3.0. But not with earlier versions.

Comment: Well, I translate with Eclipse/CDT Cygwin Miscellaneous --version and the output is: g++ (GCC) 5.3.0

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely a gcc bug. gcc has [lots of issues](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65608) with friendship and templates. This example almost exactly appears in the standard, under [class.friend], emphasis mine:

> Declaring a class to be a friend implies that the names of private and protected members from the class
>   granting friendship **can be accessed in the *base-specifiers*** and member declarations of the befriended class.
>   *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> class A {
> class B { };
>     friend class X;
> };
>
> struct X : A::B { // OK: A::B accessible to friend
>     A::B mx;      // OK: A::B accessible to member of friend
>     class Y {
>         A::B my;  // OK: A::B accessible to nested member of friend
>     };
> };
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

Comment: @VinnieFalco For what?